# How to Reuse Code with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-office

What is the best way to avoid duplicating code when working in VBA?

I'm used to languages where I can just add an import statement and get access to all a class's public properties and functions, so I can just create a utility class with some common functions and have access to that in any project I choose to import it to. Any time I want to update one of those functions, one edit is all it takes to get it working across all projects.

Is there any good way to replicate this functionality in VBA?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What follows focuses on Excel but I am pretty sure the same would apply to any Office products.

The easy way is to save your reusable code as an addin (*.xla for Excel 2003, *.xlam for Excel 2007+). You then add the addin to Excel and all the spreadsheets you open will have access to the custom functions you have in your addin. If you add specific VBA code to a spreadsheet, you can add a reference to your addin and your VBA code will have access to all the public sub, function and classes of your addin.

In my organisation, we use 3 home made addins - they are stored in C:\Program Files\OrganisationName. And everybody has access to them. When an update is made, we only need to copy the new version to everybody's hard drive and restart Excel and they have the new version.

The addins contain utilities functions such as functions to:

- read data from / write data to spreadsheets / files / databases.
- usual data manipulation such as removing duplicates from a list
- advanced statistical functions
- etc.

A few drawbacks:

- If you have several instances of Excel open, only one can update the addin, the other instances are in read-only mode
- If Excel crashes, the auto recovery mode generally does not save the changes you made on your addin (TBC on newer versions) - there are a few tools to auto save regularly

An alternative is to develop xlls or COM libraries in VB or C# for example, but this is something I have not tried.

There are plenty of tutorials online if you need a more detailed procedure.

Comment: Perfect. Got stuck for a bit because I forgot to set a reference, but once I reread your post and did that it all worked properly. Thanks :)

Comment: One of your drawbacks (updating) is solved here: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?152-Deploying-Add-ins-in-a-Network-Environment . Hope this helps anyone comming here in future.